# React native redux dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new to react redux, i am trying to dispatch an action from a connected component, but i don't know why the action was not able to reach the reducer.

## ==========================================================================================================

Below are part of my code

app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as reducers from '../reducers';
import CounterApp from './counterApp';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CounterApp />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

CounterApp.js

```
class CounterApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { state, actions } = this.props;
    return (
      <RequestScreen
        counter={state.count}
        {...actions} />
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
    state: state.counter
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(counterActions, dispatch)
  })
)(CounterApp);
```

RequestScreen

```
export class RequestScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  } 

  render() {
    const { state, actions } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.increment)}>
          <Text>up</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text>123</Text>
        <Text>{state.count}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state: state.counter
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  increment: () => { dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }) },
  decrement: () => { dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }) },
  reset: () => { dispatch({ type: 'RESET' }) },
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RequestScreen)
```

Comment: Any error in the console ?

Comment: no error ..just cant update the state

Comment: inside `const mapStateToProps` you are not returning anything so it should be  `return { state: state.counter }`

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small mistake on this line I think:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.increment)}>
```

You'll want to be calling that `increment` function within your handler:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.increment()}>
```

Or just passing it through directly

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.increment}>
```